# Variable contraint is less than zero - Linear programming

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

Suppose we have an optimization problem:

maximize $f(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ subject to a bunch of constraints followed by:

$x_1 \leq 0$,

$x_2 \geq 0$,

$x_3 \geq 0$

Can I just let some $x_4 = - x_1$, and substitute it into the objective function and all the constraints?

That way we have $x_4 \geq 0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, why wouldn't you ?  They are equivalent models.

In fact, scope of the change does not require substituting in the equations where $x_1$ appears.

Just:

- Add variable $x_4$
- Add equation $x_1=-x_4$
- Add equation $x_4\ge 0$
- Remove equation $x_1\le0$ (you can keep it but it will become redundant)